# Перемещение элемента в DOM посредством JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

Верстая очередной сайт, появилась необходимость переместить элемент в DOM, чтобы все эвенты, привязанные к нему, сохранялись.

```js
let main = document.getElementById('terminal-main');
            let input = document.getElementById('terminal-input');
            input.onkeypress = (event) => {
                if(event.key === 'Enter'){
                    let lastline = main.lastElementChild.firstElementChild;
                    input.remove();
                    lastline.innerHTML += '<span class="terminal-userline">' + input.value + '<span>';
                    let line = document.createElement('div');
                    line.className = "terminal-line";
                    line.innerHTML = '<div class="terminal-sys"><span class="terminal-user">root@kali</span>:<span class="terminal-path">~</span>#</div>';
                    main.appendChild(line);
                }
            }
```

В коде выше при нажатии на Enter нужно создать новый элемент с классом terminal-line и переместить input в него.

UPD: добавил html

```html
<div id="terminal-container">
  <div id="terminal-titlebox">
    <h3 id="terminal-title">root@kali: ~</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="terminal-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Вход</li>
      <li>Регистрация</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="terminal-main">
    <div class="terminal-line">
      <div class="terminal-sys">
        <span class="terminal-user">root@kali</span>:<span class="terminal-path">~</span>#</div>
        <input type="text" id="terminal-input">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте html  в пример.

Comment: @Igor добавил, спасибо

Comment: необходимо использовать parentEl.append(childEl) или childEl.parentNode= parentEl